# Area 51 - Remote Sensing - Any one interested in supporting this?

Tags: discussion

Just came across this [Area51 - Remote Sensing proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59346/remote-sensing). Needs support to get off the ground.

Comment: Too late, alas. It was deleterd owing to lack of activity :-(

Comment: Updated link: [Remote Sensing and Photogrammetry](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the relevant parts of [the chat exchange about this proposal](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis), which began on Aug 29.

> **WAF, 
>   Aug 29, 8:16:**
>   Hi everyone, if you want to encourage a new StackExchange website dedicated to remote sensing follow this proposal:
>   [Area 51]: Remote Sensing
>   Proposed Q&A site for remote sensing scientists and researchers
>   Currently in definition.
>
> **Andre Silva, 
>   Aug 29, 13:17:**
>   I believe a new SE site for Remote Sensing it is not necessary!
>   It overlaps with gis.se. Then, remote sensing could be (if it is not yet) just included here.
>
> **Devdatta Tengshe, 
>   Aug 30, 2:27:**
>   @WAF There are two sort of people working in GIS. Those who think that GIS is a subset of the application of Remote Sensing, and the newer lot, who think that Remote sensing is just one of the possible data sources in GIS. Personally I do not believe that there are enough people to support a distinct RS site. I'll rather have them on our site, posting questions & answering them over here.
>
> **WAF, 
>   Aug 30, 6:21:**
>   @AndreSilva @DevdattaTengshe I agree with you up to a point. There are some overlaps with GIS but as @DevdattaTengshe RS is not limited to GIS. The overarching idea is to give a centralized platform where RS people can interact.
>
> **Mingfeng, 
>   Aug 30, 8:45:**
>   Agree with @DevdattaTengshe at this point, there will not be enough people supporting a distinct RS site, and the same applies for GPS. However, RS and GPS do have their own specific questions and including those questions here in GIS SE might be inappropriate. I believe people who working with RS or GPS do not expect to find answers for their questions in GIS SE.
>   What's worth to mention is that in China, we have a term called "3S" which refers to (GIS, GPS, RS), and if there's some website related to all of these three, it's usually named as 3S blah blah. Would it be good to have a site called 3S SE which including questions in GIS, GPS and RS?
>
> **WAF, 
>   Aug 30, 9:53:**
>   @Mingfeng 3S sounds like a great idea
>
> **matt wilkie, 
>   Aug 31, 3:26:**
>   @DevdattaTengshe there aren't enough people here to support a distinct RS site. There are enough generally, out there in the wide world. Finding them all and persuading them to come visit a new honey pot though... I'm doubtful. Perhaps with a story or two about it in the Remote Sensing journals. That said, I agree with your main point. Better to collect together here than spawn further divided islands. GIS.se is still pretty small compared to the rest of the sites on the Stack Exchange network.
>   (it would be different if it were easier to search across the SE federation)
>
> **nadya, 
>   Aug 31, 22:43:**
>   @WAF 3S is not understandable to anyone outside China. Actually, GIS, GPS and RS all together with several other areas are called Geospatial Technologies or Geomatics en.wikipedia.org/wiki/…. No sense to rename it.
>   @WAF ...because university GIS courses, books and workshops usually include RS and GPS, and people know that they can find everything here, in GIS.SE.
>   Or maybe to rename GIS SE to Geospatial Technologies SE.
>
> **WAF, 
>   Sep 1, 10:21:**
>   @nadya renaming it to geomatics sounds good to me...
>
> **Michael Hamrick, 
>   Sep 4, 23:46:**
>   Geomatics sounds good to me. I wouldn't expect to get my GPS or RS questions answered at gis.se, but geomatics.se encompasses the 3S idea and could increase community involvement.

Individual members might support the idea, but the general consensus seems to be that a separate site would not garner enough attention, and RS questions are fine at GIS.SE.

Comment: Have to agree with this. Plus there are already so many RS questions here, what would happen to them?

Comment: Perhaps we should be more explicit about [**Remote Sensing questions being in-scope for GIS-SE**](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3137/should-faq-include-reference-to-remote-sensing-image-processing-and-or-surveyin).

Comment: I still don't think any changes to the FAQ are needed

Comment: I find it interesting that 75% (11 of 15) of the current Area51 supporters are not active here, a strong indicator that this community does not serve their interest or need. Whether that's because of the name -- gis.se and not rs.se -- or something else (e.g. have asked RS here and not gotten satisfactory response) is a worthy topic to explore; perhaps best on [Area 51 Discussions](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A pretty small sample size. Maybe they just don't know we handle RS questions here.

Answer (score 0):

The [Remote Sensing and Photogrammetry proposal in Area 51 was recently closed](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90327/remote-sensing-and-photogrammetry) after more than a year in the Commitment phase.